# Creating Com Error 80004005

Tags: windows, com, foxpro

Im trying to run FoxPro in Windows 2012,

I have registered the dll using regsvr32

When i try to run the app using the dll, i got this

> Error: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {F6C4F46E-58A4-4774-802F-1CF9E64376B0} from the IClassFactory failed
>   due to the following error: 80004005.  Trace:   at
>   Lib.FoxProWrapper..ctor(String ODBC, String Acct, String Pswd)    at
>   App.Processor..ctor(String SrvType, String ServiceName)    at
>   App.App.startApp()

Comment: Still throwing the same error...

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, 0x80004005 is `E_FAIL` "Unspecified error". You are thinking of 0x80070005 `E_ACCESSDENIED`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik oh yeah. IIRC 80040005 is what you get when the COM object segfaults during creation (which can be due to it being unable to load a dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume here you are talking about a COM DLL created with Visual FoxPro and by the looks of it you are trying to instantiate it in C#.

Make sure you have the runtimes properly installed. You can download them [here.](http://www.foxpert.com/runtime.htm)

Comment: Runtimes fixed the problem, i fixed it by running the prereq installer from foxpro.

Comment: Alan, care to elaborate how everythings connected? Im trying to understand this under the hood

Comment: Well, you can take a look on this Wiki: 

http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VFP9RuntimeFiles~VFP

That's assuming VFP9, there are similar pages for earlier versions. You can see there the relevant VFP DLLs and their dependencies. I'd imagine you were missing one of those.