# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005)

Tags: c#, com, visual-foxpro

When I try to instantiate a Visaul FoxPro COM DLL on a Windows 2016 server and I get the following exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Retrieving
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {8D55253A-E271-4671-9639-EC21FBE30B64} failed due to the following
>   error: 80004005 Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005
>   (E_FAIL)).
>   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

I've tried installing the [VFP 9 runtime as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30119394/185123) but I still get the same error.

If I install VFP 9 on the server I'm able to instantiate the DLL.  I **shouldn't** have to do that right?  What else should I be installing so VFP doesn't have to be installed or is that just the way VFP works?

I've inherited this dependency and I don't know much about distributing VFP COM DLLs...

Comment: Did you try registering the DLL using `regsvr32`? Did the version of the runtime you installed match the correct build target of your app (e.g., if your app is 32-bit, did you install the 32-bit VFP runtime)? How are you trying to instantiate that DLL specifically?

Comment: In addition to your VFP DLL, you'll also need the vfp9renu.dll and vfp9t.dll (or maybe the vfp9r.dll, can't remember). If you already have those, then I'm not sure what's missing.